# iOS - IB view mode

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

I'm just curious, but what is the IB View Mode even used for?

[image]

I've changed this many times with no effect? Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the way a view is filled with an image.

Try to set an image and change the values to see the difference.

Comment: I figured it had to do something with text labels and such. I guess that is what I was testing the different options with... Thanks I'll give that a try. However, why does this option then show up for UILabels and other things when they don't do anything?